# Use FilterBuilder with CompletionSuggestion in Java API

Tags: java, autocomplete, elasticsearch

I am using Java API for elastic search.
I need the autocomplete feature and for that I am using Completion

```
CompletionSuggestionBuilder compBuilder = new CompletionSuggestionBuilder("suggestapi");
compBuilder.field( field_where_search );
compBuilder.text( text_to_search );

SuggestRequestBuilder suggestRequestBuilder = client.prepareSuggest(index);
suggestRequestBuilder.addSuggestion(compBuilder);
SuggestResponse suggestResponse = suggestRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

I am getting the correct response. Now, I want to apply a Filter/query along with this suggestion. So, I need to autocomplete only for records where ["genre" : "action"]

I thought to use "BoolFilterBuilder" but did not find how to apply it to CompletionSuggestionBuilder.

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do what you want with the Completion Suggester. You would need to post filter the results yourself.

**EDIT**

You could change the way you index your completions suggestions, each genre could have its own field. The mapping would look something like:

```
{
    "movie_drama_suggest":{
        "type":"completion"
    },
    "movie_comedy_suggest":{
        "type":"completion"
    },
    "movie_horror_suggest":{
        "type":"completion"
    }
}
```

You'll need to have have logic in you application that will determine what suggestion field to use during indexing based on the genre of the movie. Then in your query you can reference the suggestions for a specific genre.

```
CompletionSuggestionBuilder compBuilder = new CompletionSuggestionBuilder("suggestapi");
compBuilder.field("movie_horror_suggest");
compBuilder.text("Ham");
```

Comment: isn't this crazy. If you are working for a video library having millions of videos, and want to implement auto-complete after applying movie_genre=comedy, you can't do this in elastic search??? So, first auto-complete should run (may give results of huge size) and then we have to apply the genre filter ourselves????

Comment: I appreciate it Dan. But this solution is not feasible for most of the cases. I have 100+ genre, which is completely normal.

Comment: "SearchRequestBuilder" has this method "addSuggestion" that takes "SuggestionBuilder" object. I was hoping it should work but it didn't work.